How to get $L^p$-estimate from $L^2$-estimate and boundedness?
Assume $M$ is compact surface, $g(t)$ satisfy the Ricci flow. $R$ is scalar curvature of $g(t)$. $\mu$ is area element of $g(t)$.  If
$$
\int_M R^2 d\mu \le Ce^{-ct} 
$$
for all $t$, then how to get the $L^p$ norm of $R$ will go to zero exponentially ?  Namely, how to show
$$
\int_M |R|^p d\mu \le Ce^{-ct}
$$
Obviously, the Holder inequality is useless. I need a inversus Holder inequality.

This problem is origin from picture below which is from Hamilton's The Ricci flow on surfaces.



Since $M$ is compact, if $1\leq p \leq 2$ then Hölder's inequality gives $$\int_M \vert R\vert^p\, d\mu \leq \vert M \vert^{1 -\frac p2} \bigg ( \int_M  R^2 \, d\mu \bigg)^{\frac p2} \leq C^{\frac p 2} \vert M \vert^{1 -\frac p2} e^{-\frac{pc}2t}. $$
If $2\leq p<+\infty$ then, since $R$ is bounded, $$\int_M \vert R\vert^p\, d\mu =\int_M \vert R\vert^{p-2} \cdot R^2\, d\mu  \leq \| R\|_{L^\infty(M)}^{p-2}\int_M \vert R\vert^{2}\, d\mu \leq C\| R\|_{L^\infty(M)}^{p-2} e^{-ct}. $$
